# ARM Assembly illegal hardware instruction ./executable

Tags: macos, assembly, arm, armv8

I am trying to execute a simple assembly program that simply indirect addresses an array.
This is my `.s` file:

```
.global _start

_start:
    ldr x0, =list

.data
list:
    .word 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6
```

But, when I assemble, link and try to execute it, I get this error:

```
$ make play
as -arch arm64 -o play.o play.s
ld -o play play.o -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64

$ ./play
[1]    2274 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
```

What is interesting is, when I keep trying to execute it, I get a different number before the "illegal hardware instruction" like so:

```
❯ ./play
[1]    2278 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2281 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2285 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2288 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2292 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2303 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2306 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2309 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2313 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2317 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
❯ ./play
[1]    2320 illegal hardware instruction  ./play
```

And it seems that the longer I wait before executing again, the difference between the numbers get larger.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Hardware: M2 chip
Architecture: Armv8 (I think M series chips use Armv8)
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1
Assembler: Aarch64

Comment: After `ldr` executes, the CPU reads the next instruction in memory which is probably all-zero bytes of padding in the executable, since you didn't put anything next.  On AArch64, they chose opcode values so that would be an illegal instruction, to catch errors like this instead of letting execution reach whatever comes after the padding.

Comment: You should add some instructions to prevent execution from running into undefined area after `ldr x0, =list`. These may be an infinite loop or a system call to exit the process.

Comment: The number before the error is probably just the Unix process-ID.  Like bash or zsh `echo $$` to see the shell's own PID?

Comment: @MikeCAT @Peter Cordes ok, so I just added a `mov x1, #2` instruction right under the `ldr` instruction and I still get the same problem (and yes, I reassembled and linked it).

Comment: If you do `true &`, the shell should similarly show the PIDs of the background child processes, and they should be monotonically increasing but maybe with gaps from other processes starting on your system.

Comment: @PeterCordes I got `1281` for the PID

Comment: `mov x1, #2` doesn't make an exit system call, so execution still continues into padding after it.  Run your code under a debugger like LLDB or GDB so you can see what instruction faults, and single-step to verify that the instructions you did write are executing first.

Comment: @PeterCordes I got this with command `true &` :                                                            ```[1] 2583
[1]  + 2583 done       true```

Comment: Ok yeah, so the numbers in your SIGILL error messages are also PID numbers printed by the shell.  The kernel allocates PIDs in sequence, usually wrapping around at 2^16 or 2^32.  (Then skipping in-use PIDs.)  Numbers in the low thousands are normal for a system that rebooted not too long ago.